# Which of the Completeness Properties of $\mathbb{R}$ imply the Archimedean Property of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Completeness Properties of $\mathbb{R}$: Least Upper Bound Property, Monotone Convergence Theorem, Nested Intervals Theorem, Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem, Cauchy Criterion.

Archimedean Property: $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}\forall \epsilon >0\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:n\epsilon >x$

I can show that LUB implies the Archimedean Property but what about the rest of these properties? Please provide proofs (even hints) or counterexamples.

EDIT: It was shown by Isaac Solomon that the Bolzano-Weierstrass implies the Archimedean Property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bolzano-Weierstrass $\to$ Archimedean Property: Take $\epsilon > 0$, and consider the sequence $\{n\epsilon: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. If the Archimedean Property fails, then this sequence is bounded, so that it has a convergent subsequence. However, it is easy to see that this sequence does not have a convergent subsequence.

---

For Monotone Convergence Theorem $\to$ Archimedean Property: Taking the same sequence $\{n\epsilon: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, it is easy to see that it is monotone. If the Archimedean Property fails, then this sequence is bounded, so by the MCT, it would have a finite limit, which is not the case.

Comment: How can you prove it has no finite limit or in the first proof that there exists no such subsequence without using the Archimedean?

Comment: A sequence $x_{n}$ converges to a limit $L$ if for every $\delta > 0$ there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$, $|x_{n} - L| < \delta$. However, consider our sequence $\{n\epsilon\}$, and take $\delta < \epsilon$. No matter how large you make $N$, $(N+1)\epsilon - N\epsilon = \epsilon > \delta$, and so this sequence cannot converge.

Comment: And the one about the subsequences an be treated similarly?

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy Completeness does not imply Archimedean Property

Counterexample:  the field of formal Laurent series over R
Every Cauchy sequence converges, but the field is Non Archimedean

For a proof see: Counterexamples in Analysis by Bernard R. Gelbaum and John M. H. Olmsted, Chapter 1, Example